# Spherically symmetrical surfaces in gauss law

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry, gauss-law

Note: This is not a check my work question, this is merely an example that came to my mind while solving the following question.

> Charge distribution on a rod bent as a semicircular arc is given by L=L'sin(x) where L is the line charge density at a point on the rod. Find the ratio of potential at $c$ to a point at a distance $r$ from the center.[image]

Now, this is how I proceeded with the question. I assumed there was another similar rod enclosing it basically making it a hollow cylinder with the same charge density and exactly identical to it. Now it's very easy to conclude that at any point on the diameter net electric field is along it as any perpendicular field would not contribute to the potential difference in any case. Hence if I could just prove that any field inside this surface is zero. There would be no potential difference between the points. So if a consider a gaussian surface of radius r inside this, there is no charge inside it, hence net flux through it should be zero. Also as the net electric field at any point on this spherical Gaussian surface is parallel to the Area vector, but this electric field would not be equal at every point(we cannot conclude without integration), but the sum of positive numbers cannot be zero. Hence I conclude that at every point inside this is zero. Now I am not sure whether we can even consider this a gaussian surface as an electric field we cannot conclude to be equal. So I am correct, because the answer is that it's equal.

Comment: what is $L'$ in the formula $L=L'sin(x)$

Comment: @AdilMohammed Its a constant

Comment: Also if we are considering semicircular arc, there's no way you are getting a spherically symmetric surface, like your title suggests (unless I am wrong somewhere)

Comment: @AdilMohammed I basically constructed another semicircular arc make a hollow cylinder like object as the potential and field provided by both of them is equal, I considered a spherical surface inside them at a distance r from the center, and the rest of question.

Comment: ah i see, so you proved that there would not be any electric field if we consider 2 semicircles joined together,? I think it can also be proven by symmetry, but how did you conclude that there wouldn't be any electric field in the case of just one semicircle?